# Get XML node of index

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript, xslt

I have a `textarea` with the following xml:

```
<root>
  <header>
    <title>This is the doc title</title>
  </header>
  <body attribute="[cursor]">
    Here we have some <?cursor [cursor]?> Text or [cursor]
    <![CDATA[
      Even more text in a CDATA and <notExisting>
        <p>
          [cursor]
        </p>
      </notExisting>
    ]]>
    <cursor  [cursor] />
    or with a comment <!-- This is the [cursor] position -->
  </body>
</root>
```

Since it is a textarea i can place the cursor whereever i want. Now i want to the current tree of the cursor position.

For example in the first attribute it could something be like: `/root/body/@attribute`

or in the processing instruction
`/root/body/processing-instruction('cursor')`

Is there any way to get always the current cursor position?

Comment: So you just want the current cursor position?  Or do you want the xpath to the node where the cursor is?

Comment: I don't think this should be considered an XSLT question- your input is text, not XML, and even if it was, you're not transforming it in any way.

Comment: @bheklilr i just want the cursor position (The node)

Comment: That's going to be quite a bit of work. You'll need a way to associate the cursor position with the parsed XML, which might not even be valid XML if someone is actively editing it.

Comment: @bheklilr if the xml is not XML valid it should not work. So i can ignore this case